# Tortoise SVN - different credentials for same repository server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, credentials

I have googled a lot on internet/stack overflow, with no success. Finally came here to ask a question.

**Summary:**
Tortoise SVN - different credentials for same SVN server for different repository.

**Background:**
I have two different SVN repositories created on our intranet server. Out of which,

1. One is shared among a group members (we call it TechnicalGroup) -
   https://intranet/svn/TG. This repo is accessible thru a common
   username (say TG).
2. Second is just for my current project -
   https://intranet/svn/PrjBala. This repo is accessible thru an
   individual username (say bala).

**Problem:**
Both these repos are created on same SVN server (i.e. URL). Now once checking out first repo (i.e. TG), if I am trying to checkout 2nd one (i.e. bala), it is directly checking out with "TG" and not prompting me for credentials.

**Solution required:**
I want to set "TG"-credentials for first repo and "bala"-credentials for second repo. I am using Tortoise SVN.

Please help/guide me to achieve my goal.

Comment: This is easily done with PuTTY via SSH access to the SVN repository server, but probably rather difficult or impossible to do with HTTPS access.  Do you have the option of using SSH to talk to the SVN server?

Comment: If you clear you credentials and don't save them, you could enter your credentials on every interaction with the server.

Comment: @tgharold,
PuTTY SSH is not possible, since I don't have access to SVN server.

Comment: @RjOllos,
If I choose the way you shown, every time I get SVN update / commit, I have to enter credentials??!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm three years late for the party but I came here while looking for an answer to the same question (and yeah, we are still using SVN...).

You can edit your hosts file and create a new entry there pointing to the same IP address of your SVN server, for instance:

```
192.168.0.100 intranet-svn-tg intranet-svn-bala
```

And then, for project TG, you'd use https://intranet-svn-tg/svn/TG and for PrjBala you should use https://intranet-svn-bala/svn/PrjBala. In theory, this should have your credentials saved differently for them.

It works as expected in my Linux machine, I haven't tested it on windows but I believe it will work the same.

If you need information on how to edit the hosts file, I hope this will be helpful: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/

Comment: yes @leonardo, practically your trick should work. Thank a ton for ur idea. :)